# Blinking caret on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, .net-core, textbox

I have been finding that “Windows Forms App (.NET Core)” projects lack the functionality of normal “.NET framework” apps. I'm specifically using .NET Core 3.1.

I have a textbox that I added to the form through the designer in Visual Studio C#, and I can't find a way to make the caret blink. It just shows a constant solid line when the textbox has focus. The Win32 APIs don't seem to help and I can't find anything on the System.Windows.Forms.TextBox or its parent classes.

Does anyone know how I might go about getting the caret to blink in the text box?

[Edit] It seems that this might be a bug in .NET core, that is also in .NET Core v5. I'm submitting a bug report on github.

Comment: I've been able to replicate the issue-sort of. Mine blinks 5-6 times then stops blinking. However, after a while it starts blinking again. The process seams to repeat.

Comment: @user Oh yeah, you're right.  That's...weird. Seems like a bug. That behaviour seems to be present in .NET 5 too.

Comment: OP, I would suggest creating an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms

Comment: I'm using VS 2019 (v 16.11.5), have [.NET SDK 5.0.403](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) installed (found by typing "dotnet --version" in a "cmd" window), and selected `.NET Core 3.1`.

Comment: @Llama - I'll add a bug report on Github then. Not sure if its appropriate, but I'll update my question to mention this. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that after the cursor stops blinking, if one clicks (the mouse) inside the TextBox, the cursor will start blinking again.

Comment: @use You are describing the default behavior of edit controls. To verify this, open Notepad and observe the caret's behavior. This is built into the system and cannot be changed (unless you're willing to re-implement the functionality entirely).

Comment: @IInspectable Interesting. You're absolutely right. I'd never noticed that befoe.

Comment: @lla That's probably because it hasn't always been like that. There used to be a time when the caret was blinking indefinitely. I don't know when nor why this was changed, though I do know that it has caused more confusion than is healthy for a feature that gets rolled out to billions of devices.

Comment: Notepad blinks for me, but I am running Windows 7

Comment: @IInspectable Oh wow. I still have VMs for Win10 RTM and v1803, so naturally I had to fire them up. Looks like it stopped blinking sometime between 2015 and 2018..